Statement Vs Proposition Vs Premise Vs Assertion
I have spent a few days running around the internet trying to find a distinct and simple explanation of how all of these terms fit together. I'm aware it is quite nuanced.
Could someone help me resolve this issue? I'm sure there are many others who find your answer helpful.
Thank you!

See e.g. this post as well as sentence vs proposition.

Thanks - I've got it!

You are welcome !

And see What is the meaning of assertion? and What is the difference between statement and premise?

Useful: Propositions and Assertion.


A proposition is that which is true or false, but not true and false simultaneously.

A proposition is beyond language.

A statement is that which symbolizes a proposition, so a statement must be formulated in a language.

A statement is a referrer, that refers to a proposition.  A proposition is a referent, that is symbolized by a referrer.
Examples of statements

I am hungry.
My eyes are closed.
It is raining.
Tomorrow there will be a sea battle.
Nothing is alive.
There is a beginning of time.
1+1=2
Some matter exists.
X exists if and only if X is in the current moment in time.

The word premise is always used in the context of an argument.
You have an argument when it is asserted that given some set of propositions are true, another proposition follows. The former propositions are called the premises of the argument, the latter proposition is called the conclusion of the argument.   The premises are the propositions given to be true.  Arguments consisting of one premise are possible.  To every argument there corresponds a statement called the corresponding conditional.
Argument: A1,A2,...,An; therefore B
Has corresponding conditional
If A1 and A2 and... and An then B.
So a one premise argument has a corresponding conditional
If A then B, where A is its single premise.
An assertion is a statement that is stated to symbolize a true proposition.
There is confusion about the use of the term statement.  Many people use the term statement when they mean proposition.  Their confusion stems from the original meaning of the word statement.
Classical Definition
A statement is that which is true or false, but not true and false in the same state.
A state is a moment in time.
Thus an equivalent definition is:
A statement is that which is true or false but not true and false simultaneously.

Hi! Thank you for this. From my collective understanding: Sentence= is a meaningful group of words that express a statement, question, exclamation, request, command or suggestion.  Statement = declarative sentence - sentence that declares fact[s] Proposition = statement that is either true or false not both Assertion = proposition claimed to be true Premise = propositions [assertions] that are selected to draw inferences [with the intention of reasoning to a conclusion in arguments] This seems to make logical sense.. thank you!

Your distinction of using “statement” for the linguistic expression and “proposition” for its denotation is not common/standard in my experience (mostly from mathematical logic) — in the literature I’m familiar with, both of them are more typically used for the linguistic/syntactic expression, and sometimes also for the denotation.  If this distinction is more established as standard in some other field, could you say where, and ideally give a reference?

Without getting technical [im no technical expert] through the lense of philosopihcal thought not mathematical:
I view it through the lense of interpretation: before a proposition can be deemed to be truth bearing, it has to first exist as something that is declared. For something that is declared [statement] to have exist it has to have been uttered as a group of words [in the form of a sentence].
In the same way whilst propositions are truth bearing, assertions qualify propositions as assumed to be true, which qualify as premises when forming an argument.
Open to objections!

I would like to note that in my interpretation what qualifies a statement to be a proposition is its form - the form of the statement determines whether the statement qualifies to be something that is expressed as true or false

@Peter, In Irving M. Copi's 'Symbolic Logic',  he makes the distinction between proposition and statement in chapter 1.  He says, a proposition is that which is true or false.  So I got my use of the word 'proposition' from him.  He also says in the same breath, that the term statement is used for the linguistic formulation of a proposition.  Then he says, in the later chapters he will use the terms interchangeably.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I think you are correct that the proposition/statement distinction is used in various ways. Many writers use them interchangeably. Strawson prefers to reserve statement for what a speaker means by an utterance, taking into account context, etc. So a sentence can express many different statements, with different truth values, depending on who utters it and when. Propositions are often thought of as language-independent, though it is highly controversial whether there is such a thing. Assertions are speech acts.

In order to keep things simple, as a first step I propose the following definitions:

Statement = proposition: A sentence which can be either true or
false.

Assertion: Asserting a proposition means to claim that the
proposition is true, not false.

Premise: The first part A of an implication “A implies B”. Here A, B
are two propositions.
In the second step, some authors discriminate between a proposition and a statement. I for myself do not understand what they mean. But I am sure, that some experts on this side can - and hopefully will - explain it :-)



Hi Jo! My current thinking to date has been similar:
Statements = declarative sentences = a descriptive sentence that conveys information
Proposition = Statements that are truth-bearing
Premise = propositions that are selected to draw inferences [with the intention of reasoning to a conclusion in arguments]
